# BPMN 2.0 visualize process with intermediate event

Tags: diagram, bpmn

i got a question. I'm using Visual Paradigm for BPMN 2.0. I want to visualize one Pool with two Lanes. One Lane is sending a document into the other Lane in the same Pool. I used an "Intermediate Event" to send such a document. Is that right? How would you guys build it? 
[image]
The second thing is, what i learned is to use a "Message-Flow"-Connection when i'm using the "Intermediate Event". When i use this connection an error occurs.
"Invalid..." shown in the picture below.
[image]
How would you visualize the "send document" from lane a in lane b, so that everything works fine?

Regards

new picture:
[image: send document, edit the document and send it back]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages can be passed between different pools only (and then you use events to pass them). If you want to pass a document within one pool (regardless if one or more lanes) you need to show it in parallel to the flow, with a document icon in a form of a sheet with a folded corner and dashed between process steps and document.

Please see example on page 26 of this official OMG document:

http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100601/10-06-02.pdf

Comment: is the new picture right then? so a document is sent and i have to add a normal sequence flow to that action, where the document is sent?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you should model it.
P.S. Please if you find my answer useful, vote it up and mark it as a solution to your question.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing just with a different pool? So i want to send a document into another pool? is that visualized with a intermediate event then? How can i do that? Pool A -> Lane A --> E-Mail to --> Pool B -> Lane B. What kind of connection i got then? a message flow? Can u show me how to do that? :-)

Comment: Yes, the information between pools is exchanged through messages that are send and received by message events (the event might be a part of activity with only activity visible, you may also have a "black box" view of a pool, especially external one and then you just show a message connected to the pool as a whole). This is the only valid method of exchanging information between pools. process flow cannot jump between pools as each pool has its own process handling this information exchange, even though they might be synchronized (thanks to send and received messages of course).

Comment: Where is the difference with sending a Message which is integrated in the action and the Message seperated from an action? What do you mean with a black box view of a pool? Can u create an graphical example for me to understand that in general?Thanks for your reply :-) That helped a lot

Comment: Please take a look at that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743500/how-do-i-illustrate-both-sides-of-a-transaction-in-bpmn/26745158#26745158 
You have there both examples of black box/collapsed pool (Customer on the last example) and messages either with explicit event (Call on Pizza service side, event "Phone call received") or sent/received within activity without details about message event (Advice and Order on Pizza service side, handled in activity "Advise customer and receive order").